# Create deep link with custom data branch.io (react-native)

Tags: react-native, branch.io

I need to create deep link with custom data, I want to add as a parameter userId, how can I do this?

My idea was using something like this, but I got an error "`await is reserved word`".

```
let linkProperties = {
      feature: 'share',
      channel: 'facebook',
      userId: "125",
  }

  let controlParams = {
       $desktop_url: 'http://desktop-url.com/monster/12345'
  }

  let {url} = await branchUniversalObject.generateShortUrl(linkProperties, controlParams)
  return url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it's possible to achieve this by using such code

```
let branchUniversalObject = await branch.createBranchUniversalObject('canonicalIdentifier', {
  title: 'Cool Content!',
  contentDescription: 'Cool Content Description'}),
  contentMetadata: {
    customMetadata: {
      userId: "125", // your userId field would be defined under customMetadata
    }
  }
})

 async shareReferralLink () {
    let linkProperties = {
      feature: 'share',
      channel: 'facebook',
      userId: "125",
  }

  let controlParams = {
       $desktop_url: 'http://desktop-url.com/monster/12345'
  }

  let {url} = await branchUniversalObject.generateShortUrl(linkProperties, controlParams)
  console.log("URL ", url)
}
```

Or another solution is create short link in branch.io dashboard, and then add data in the add of the link, simply by adding `?usedId=1234`, so link will look like this: `https://test.app.link/home?userId=1234`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is resolved.The data can be added as query parameters as you mentioned. Please feel free to reach out us at integrations@branch.io in case of any further questions!